# update textbox when using multi thread vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

My code

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
Dim thread As System.Threading.Thread
Dim thread2 As System.Threading.Thread
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf getproxy)
    thread.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub getproxy()
    Try
        Dim ip As String = "76.125.85.66:16805 | 0.238 | Little Rock | AR | Unknown | United States69.207.212.76:49233 | 0.274 | Sayre | PA | 18840 | United States96.42.127.190:25480 | 0.292 | Sartell | MN | 56377 | United States"
        For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(ip, "(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}:\d+")
            TextBox1.Text += (m.Value) & vbNewLine
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

i want it show textbox all proxy format

```
76.125.85.66:16805
69.207.212.76:49233
96.42.127.190:25480
```

but it error

{"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'TextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access control from the UI thread once you start a thread. You can [Invoke](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fzyzhdc6b(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ei=kReOVeOFGsOHsAWe0YyYCA&usg=AFQjCNF3NbRqNaErwkJFB8DwAdQJZ20ddw&sig2=Pdf629jzX8X7_z5icug6wg&bvm=bv.96783405,d.b2w) the UI thread and update the textbox.

```
Private Sub getproxy()
    Dim ip As String = "76.125.85.66:16805 | 0.238 | Little Rock | AR | Unknown | United States69.207.212.76:49233 | 0.274 | Sayre | PA | 18840 | United States96.42.127.190:25480 | 0.292 | Sartell | MN | 56377 | United States"
    Me.Invoke(Sub() 
     For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(ip, "(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}:\d+")         
      TextBox1.Text += (m.Value) & Enviroment.NewLine
     Next
               End Sub)
End Sub
```

PS why do you need a thread for this work? Seems like this would take little time to perform. Threading is for long process work.

Answer (score 0):

Is there actually more work going on inside `getproxy()`?

At any rate, you should only `Invoke()` the code that is actually updating the UI.  The rest of the code should run in the other thread:

```
Private Sub getproxy()
    Try
        Dim ip As String = "76.125.85.66:16805 | 0.238 | Little Rock | AR | Unknown | United States69.207.212.76:49233 | 0.274 | Sayre | PA | 18840 | United States96.42.127.190:25480 | 0.292 | Sartell | MN | 56377 | United States"
        For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(ip, "(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}:\d+")

            ' ... possibly some other work done with "m.Value" ...

            ' Invoke just the updating of the UI itself:
            TextBox1.Invoke(Sub()
                                TextBox1.AppendText(m.Value & vbNewLine)
                            End Sub)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```